# Python, Pandas, Selenium append/insert zeros into empty cells

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, dataframe

This is for a personal project of mine. The OS that I am using is Windows 10.  The IDE I am using is pycharm. I am coding in python and I am using selenium and pandas libraries.

Some things that I have tried are `list.insert(k, '0')` in the for loop before all the if statements, `np.where(pd.isnull(df))` after creating the dataframe, and `if df.empty: df.append('0')`. I tried `[0] * num_page_items` but that got really messy. I decided to go the series route because I read that NaN would be placed into the empty cells but that did not workout how I intended. When I tried to use the data frame it did not work because the arrays are not of the same size.

What I want to achieve is to place zeros in the empty cells and align the prices with the respective name, type, and weights. I have attached pictures and my code to help you understand. Is there a way I can place zeros into the empty cells before creating the dataframe?

[image: What my current code gives me]
 <sup>*Current results*</sup>

[image: What I want]
 <sup>*What I am want to achieve*</sup>

Here is my code.

```
# Import libraries
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

# Open the google chrome browser and navigate to website
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH)

# Total amount of pages to web scrape
MAX_PAGE_NUM = 4

# Initialize lists
half = list()
oneg = list()
eighth = list()
quarter = list()
half = list()
oneoz = list()
each = list()

# Iterate through the pages and web scrape
for i in range(1, MAX_PAGE_NUM + 1):
    url = "https://weedmaps.com/deliveries/callweed-2?page=" + str(i)
    driver.get(url)
    print(url)

    # Find the elements by using xpath
    product_name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class ="styled-components__Name-sc-186ferk-9 lbdlVL"]')
    product_type = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class ="styled-components__BrandCategory-sc-186ferk-6 dTklNg"]')
    prices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="styled-components__Price-sc-6ubro-3 dEwZFC"]')
    weight = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0 src__Flex-sc-1sbtrzs-1 styled-components__UnitLabel-sc-6ubro-1 dGTmZk"]')
    wordEach = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0 src__Flex-sc-1sbtrzs-1 styled-components__UnitLabel-sc-6ubro-1 dGTmZk"]')

    # Get the length of the products
    num_page_items = len(product_name)

    # Store the product names and the types in respective lists
    products = [product_name[j].text for j in range(num_page_items)]
    types = [product_type[j].text for j in range(num_page_items)]

   # Append prices to respective lists
    for k in range(num_page_items):
        if weight[k].text == '1/2 g':
            half.append(prices[k].text)
        elif weight[k].text == '1 g':
            oneg.append(prices[k].text)
        elif weight[k].text == '1/8 oz':
            eighth.append(prices[k].text)
        elif weight[k].text == '1/4 oz':
            quarter.append(prices[k].text)
        elif weight[k].text == '1/2 oz':
            half.append(prices[k].text)
        elif weight[k].text == '1 oz':
            oneoz.append(prices[k].text)
        elif wordEach[k].text == 'each':
            each.append(prices[k].text)


    # Create a data frame
    # d = {'Name': products, 'Type': types, '1/2 g': half, '1 g': oneg, '1/8 oz': eighth, '1/4 oz': quarter, '1/2 oz': half, '1 oz': oneoz, 'Each': each}
    # df = pd.Series(d, index=['Name', 'Type', '1/2 g', '1 g', '1/8 oz', '1/4 oz', '1/2 oz', '1 oz', 'Each'])
    # df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    # Create series and concat
    s1 = pd.Series(products, name='Name')
    s2 = pd.Series(types, name='Type')
    s3 = pd.Series(half, name='1/2 g')
    s4 = pd.Series(oneg, name='1g')
    s5 = pd.Series(eighth, name='1/8 oz')
    s6 = pd.Series(quarter, name='1/4 oz')
    s7 = pd.Series(half, name='1/2 oz')
    s8 = pd.Series(oneoz, name='1 oz')
    s9 = pd.Series(each, name='Each')
    df = pd.concat([s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9], axis=1)

    # Any cells that are empty fill them with NAN
    # np.where(pd.isnull(df))

    # Wait 3 seconds after webscraping each page
    time.sleep(3)

# When done close the driver
# driver.close()

#Save to the following location
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\jo\oside_callW.csv', index=False, header=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')
print(df)
```

Comment: Did df.fillna(0) didn't work for you?

Comment: I just tried it. It did not work.

Comment: Please try df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

Comment: That worked but I am still having the issue of having the zeros and prices in the correct locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my question. I used comprehensive lists to to make the code smaller. Using the following if statement `if weight[k].text == 'some weight'else '0'` in the comprehensive list.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

# Open the google chrome browser and navigate to website
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH)

# Total amount of pages to web scrape
MAX_PAGE_NUM = 4

# An empty list that will be used to append data frames
dflist = list()

# Iterate through the pages and web scrape
for i in range(1, MAX_PAGE_NUM + 1):
    url = "https://weedmaps.com/deliveries/callweed-2?page=" + str(i)
    driver.get(url)
    print(url)

    # Find the elements by using xpath
    product_name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class ="styled-components__Name-sc-186ferk-9 lbdlVL"]')
    product_type = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class ="styled-components__BrandCategory-sc-186ferk-6 dTklNg"]')
    prices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="styled-components__Price-sc-6ubro-3 dEwZFC"]')
    weight = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0 src__Flex-sc-1sbtrzs-1 styled-components__UnitLabel-sc-6ubro-1 dGTmZk"]')
    wordEach = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="src__Box-sc-1sbtrzs-0 src__Flex-sc-1sbtrzs-1 styled-components__UnitLabel-sc-6ubro-1 dGTmZk"]')

    # Get the length of the products
    num_page_items = len(product_name)
    num_prices = len(prices)

    # Store the product names and the types in respective lists
    products = [product_name[j].text for j in range(num_page_items)]
    types = [product_type[j].text for j in range(num_page_items)]

    # Append prices to respective lists
    halfg = [prices[k].text if weight[k].text == '1/2 g'else '0' for k in range(num_page_items)]
    oneg = [prices[k].text if weight[k].text == '1 g'else '0' for k in range(num_page_items)]
    eighth = [prices[k].text if weight[k].text == '1/8 oz'else '0' for k in range(num_page_items)]
    quarter = [prices[k].text if weight[k].text == '1/4 oz'else '0' for k in range(num_page_items)]
    halfoz = [prices[k].text if weight[k].text == '1/2 oz'else '0' for k in range(num_page_items)]
    oneoz = [prices[k].text if weight[k].text == '1 oz'else '0' for k in range(num_page_items)]
    each = [prices[k].text if weight[k].text == 'each' else '0' for k in range(num_page_items)]

    # Create a data frame
    d = {'Name': products, 'Type': types, '1/2 g': halfg, '1 g': oneg, '1/8 oz': eighth, '1/4 oz': quarter,'1/2 oz': halfoz, '1 oz': oneoz, 'Each': each}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    # Append the data frame after each iteration
    dflist.append(df)

    # Wait 3 seconds after web scraping each page
    time.sleep(3)

# When done close the driver
# driver.close()

# Concatenate all of the data frame
df = pd.concat(dflist)

#Save to the following location
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\jo\oside_callW.csv.csv', index=False, header=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')
print(df)
```